# Autodesk Inventor drawed/engraved lines

Tags: autodesk-inventor

I have to model a laser engraved and cut body in Autodesk Inventor.

How can I design a model with engraved surface on it (simple for example a circle engraved). I need to make a presentation of it.

What I tried:

1. Made a sketch with a rectangle (for example 20mm×20mm).
2. Extrude 3 mm
3. Made another sketch on the surface of the rectangle.
4. Draw a circle on it (it is the engraved shape)

This resulted in that the circle is visible in the assembly, but not visible in the presentation. So this is not a solution, because I need to see the circle in the presentation. So seems to me this is not a good way.

Thank you your help!

Tibor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options.

1. Cut the circle (0.1 mm)
2. Split face by circle
3. Insert image to the sketch and project it on the face (decal command)
4. Create texture for engraving.

Some useful links

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Inventor-Help/files/GUID-53D2D220-7053-4851-AAA4-2A2AEE489E1E-htm.html

https://help.autodesk.com/view/INVNTOR/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-75E1FB55-B4E0-46A3-8345-E42CA423C6D2